# How to do a reactive assignment across multiple lines in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

In Svelte, it's common to assign variables that are reactively computed from some props or state like so:

```js
    export let x: number
    export let y: number
    $: sum = x + y
```

What does the multi-line form of this look like, when I have a reaction significantly more complicated than `x + y`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will always recommend putting an operation that is mildly complex (or worse, obviously) into a function of its own, and then call that function with the variables you want the operation to react on. It will improve readability and reusability and clarify intent.

I would also encourage making these functions pure whenever you can (i.e. no side effects) but that isn't always possible.

So for instance, rather than having something like this:

```js
$: {
    ...multi-line complex operation on x and y setting value z...
}
```

I would do this:

```js
function complexOperation(a, b) {
  ...multi-line complex operation on a and b setting value c...
  return c
}

$: z = complexOperation(x, y)
```

I try to keep all my reactive statements into one-liners, otherwise I move them into functions of their own, but I understand that's personal preference.

Comment: Thanks! I've ended up mostly doing them as anonymous function invocations like `$: pattern = ((allPatterns) => { return allPatterns.find(p => p.id === patternId) })(allPatterns)`. It's not quite as nice as reactive getters in Vue or Mobx, but I think it's alright.

Comment: You're welcome! Although in the example you give, an anonymous function is not necessary, you could simply do `$: pattern = allPatterns.find(p => p.id === patternId)` which I think is clearer?

Comment: Yep, sorry, bad example; I do mean specifically for the case when multiple statements are needed.

Answer (score 1):

The extended version of this is

```
$: if (valesChanged) {
    // do whatever you want
}
```

And the condition could be a change of one or more of the reactive values.

or more elegant solution if there any change in all props

```
$: if($$props) {
    console.log($$props)
}
```